# Simultaneous vs sequential key combinations

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Some programs use sequential key combinations: `screen`, `ratpoison`, `vim`: you press a key and release it and now you press the command key.

Others use simultaneous keys e.g. `firefox` quits with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

What determines which approach to take when designing the UI?

Comment: Look up n key rollover.  A lot of times there is a maximum number of key presses which alters this effect slightly(assuming I understand your question correctly.)

Comment: `vim`, at least, can combine both methods. You can, for example, define the simultaneous press of `Ctrl-A` followed by a sequential press of `q` to do one thing, and `Ctrl-A` followed by `w` to do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on how many commands you need to support.  Chorded key combinations typically involve only a small number of modifier keys and therefore are more limited, whereas sequential key combinations can be arbitrarily long and thus are more scalable.

Unless your application needs to support a large number of commands, I would use chorded combinations since they are more common, simpler, and more direct.

Also note that they aren't mutually exclusive.  Sequential key combinations often need to be triggered by an initial chorded key combination anyway.  Additionally, some applications use chorded key combinations for their most common commands and use sequential ones for less common commands.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an approach based on what your users prefer and expect based on their previous experiences. If this app is for engineers who use use code editors that compile scripts, then then that seems to fit. However, if they all use Photoshop, this method would never apply.